# Automatic deployment of bot service on azure using C#

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I need to be able to deploy bot framework solution fully automatically from a .net web app.
The resources I am able to create with ease (using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) are:

- app service plan
- Web App with bot backend
- azure storage

The resources that I **want** (and can't) are:

- "Wab App Bot"
- "Cognitive Service" with LUIS (this one is optional for know, but it would be really great if I can also create this kind of resource from code)

I have configured service principal with necessary rights.

Comment: ok, whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the code samples to create Azure app bot and Cognitive Service under the SDKs.

Azure app bot https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/BotService

Azure Cognitive Service https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/CognitiveServices

Comment: Any documentation or some how-to to these projects? Or starting point?

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/README.md

Answer (score -1):

My though on this to enable the continious deployment for the bt code using GitHub or AzureDevOps, following link will help you set up the CD for the bot
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

As for the LUIS application, what I end up doing is to use PowerShell / C# app to deploy the LUIS app definition using the LUIS REST api https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f